# MongoDB slow $mergeCursors

Tags: mongodb-3.2

I have Mongodb 3.2.6 with 4 shards. Each shards has 4 replica.

My db is working perfect but suddenly it is showing $mergeCursors on one collection is running slow and made whole DB response slow!!, sometimes it resolves fast, sometimes it makes Mongo response unstable for more than 30 minutes while I can not see any long-running query.

So question is How can i find reason/Query related to this slowness? For More info i should say CurrentOP don't show query and it is reflecting $mergeCusror as long running.

Slowness log is as below:

> 2017-10-18T18:11:33.437+0330 DB.colservice command: aggregate {
>   aggregate: "Service", pipeline: [ { $mergeCursors: [ { host:
>   "hodt0:27000", id: 798236908 }, { host: "host1:27100", id:
>   157434398368 }, { host: "host2:27200", id: 80616205236 }, { host:
>   "host3:27300", id: 75977221429 } ] } ] } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0
>   numYields:0 reslen:6227 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } },
>   Database: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r:
>   2 } } } protocol:op_command 9759ms

Comment: You must be running some aggregation that is pulling data from all 4 shards and merging the data to create one result set.

Comment: Yes, But I need to have exact query and I am not sure if it is query performance issue or Some other issues.

Comment: You are not seeing this with `currentOp()` because the query is in merge phase. I suggest you set up Profiler with with some filters so you can get the query next time you see the same behavior. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Comment: I have profile in level 2 and check it by system.profile But cant find main query which is getting slow in mergeCursour section.